# Paste a copied image into an AIR iOS app?

Tags: ios, air, clipboard, copy-paste

Is it possible to paste a copied image from the Safari browser to an Adobe AIR built iOS app?
I tried it with [this image](http://static.pexels.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/animals-cats-cute-4602-825x550.jpg) but couldn't find a solution yet.
Below is a screenshot of the `copy` button from the Safari browser on iOS 8: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. You can't use the native dialogs or handling, but I believe you can access the data in the clipboard, even if it is an image.

You'll want to use [`Clipboard#getData()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html#getData()) with a format of [`ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/ClipboardFormats.html#BITMAP_FORMAT). That will give you access to the raw image data in a `BitmapData` object. You can then draw that `BitmapData` to a `Bitmap` container (or `Image`/`BitmapImage` if using Flex). You'll have to include a separate button for instantiating the paste process, but that isn't difficult to do.

Untested, but this should be a good place to start:

```
pasteButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.pasteEventHandler);

function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var clipboard:Clipboard = new Clipboard()
    var bd:BitmapData = clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT);
    bitmap.bitmapData = bd;
}
```

I believe you'll need to handle errors in there as well, since the clipboard could contain text would either throw an error on the `getData()` line or return null.

Comment: Just tried it and the clipboard is empty - my code: `btnpaste.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pasteEventHandler);
 
function pasteEventHandler(e:Event = null):void
{
var clipboardImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT) as BitmapData);
addChild(clipboardImage)
}` Is it an AIR bug?

Comment: @Matt If you inspect the `BitmapData` outputted by `getData()` (I'd set it to its own variable to easily inspect it), is it null? Haven't done an non-Flex project in a while, so I am a bit rusty with `Bitmap`. I seem to remember that you have to set its height manually; it doesn't inherit from the `BitmapData`. If the `BitmapData` isn't null, my guess is you need to set the height of the `Bitmap` object.

Comment: Yes, it's null. Does copy and paste work for native Xcode build apps?

Comment: @Matt Yes it does. I've gotten Bitmap copying working with Flash before and I've used the Clipboard on iOS and Android before as well. Not sure why it's not working, unfortunately. Sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: It works within the Flash IDE but not on the iOS device. Please let me know if find a solution.